# 'Invalid constant value error' of Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

Although a variable is initialized in initState, I encountered the 'Invalid constant value' problem.

Could you please explain why this occurs?

I've annotated key points in the code.

Thank you.

P.S: I'm using Flutter 3.16.5 and Dart 3.2.3

```
class _LoadingScreenState extends State<LoadingScreen>
    with TickerProviderStateMixin {
  
  AnimationController? _animationController; // !Declare!

  @override
  void initState() {
    _animationController = AnimationController(   // !Initialization in initState!
      vsync: this,          
    );
  }

  @override
  void dispose() {
    _animationController?.dispose();
    super.dispose();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return const Scaffold(
      body: ClipRect(
        child: Stack(children: [
          WelcomeView(
            animationController: _animationController!,  // !I got invalid constant value issue here! 
          ),
        ]),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove the `const` keyword before the `Scaffold` widget.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
       
  }
```

Comment: Thank you! It works. Could you let me know why I shouldn't use const in this case?

Comment: Because you are using dynamic (non final) variable in the widget that's why you cannot declare the widget as constant.

Answer (score 1):

> To resolve this issue, you should not use the const keyword when creating the Scaffold widget in the build method, and you should not use the const keyword when passing _animationController to the WelcomeView. Here's the modified code:

@override
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
return Scaffold(
body: ClipRect(
child: Stack(
children: [
WelcomeView(
animationController: _animationController!,
),
],
),
),
);
}

Comment: Thank you very much Mathivanan! It's crystal clear!